# Can i set a custom CONCAT() for each row in a select query? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple rows that need a different concat function.
The table looks like this

```
A B C D E F
-----------
1 H E Y
2 T H E E R
3 W O R D L
```

I want to add another column with the word concatenated which i've done like this

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(B, C, D) AS G FROM table
```

Obviously it returns

```
A B C D E F G
-------------
1 H E Y     HEY
2 T H E E R THE
3 W O R D L WOR
```

is there a way to get the result to be

```
A B C D E F G
-------------
1 H E Y     HEY
2 T H E E R THERE
3 W O R D L WORLD
```

The answer addresses the simplified question:

How do you combined these 3 select statements into 1?

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(C, B, E, D, F) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 1; 
SELECT *, CONCAT(G, C, D, B, E, F) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 2; 
SELECT *, CONCAT(D, E, F, C, B) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 3;
```

Comment: What about `TRIM(CONCAT(B, C, D, E, F))`?

Comment: Are the blank columns NULL or do they have empty strings? And you want to make THERE from T H E E R in that order but WORLD from W O R L D?

Comment: Row 3 is different in examples 1,2 and 3. Please precise

Comment: Problem is that they aren't going to be in order of b, c, d, e, f every time

Comment: @RickyRoller How do you know what order they should be in?  We can't write a query if we don't know what the algorithm should be.

Comment: Whatever the criteria is, you should be able to express it using `IF` or `CASE`.

Comment: You said `CONCAT(B, C, D, F, E)` twice, is that what you mean? How does it decide which CONCAT is used for each row?

Comment: @cdhowie I put the CONCAT functions in there now. the concat function will be the same for each row every time, the order is just user input, not a calculated algorithm or anything like that.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what this is trying to accomplish, we'd understand it better. What do these columns represent?

Comment: @RickyRoller I understand which invocations you want for which row, but *how is this determined?*  Do you intend to hard-code that the record where A=1 has one `CONCAT()` call while 2 and 3 have another?  Is there some other column (or row in another table) that could be used to deduce the order in which the characters should be concatenated?

Comment: @Barmar In this case I'm trying to accomplish un scrambling a word and putting the correct word in it's own column: G

Comment: So you want to try all permutations, and use the one that's a real word? I think it would be best to write a user-defined function to do this -- if you want to do it in straight SQL you'd have to list all 120 permutations. How does it know which ordering is correct?

Comment: @cdhowie No, there won't be anything else that has the value for determining the order of the concat. It is a small query of only 10 rows that will feed into an application so the individual concats will just be hard-coded into the select statement

Comment: Why is the answer for row 2 `THERE` instead of `THREE`?

Comment: @barmar I know what the values are so there is no need to list out permutations to figure out what it is. I know that it is THERE and not three. I realize that since i know the end values you'd probably just say make another column with the values but in this case i can't do that

Comment: You know, but how does the COMPUTER know? Computer programming is all about describing **algorithms**. There has to be a process for the computer to follow.

Comment: Ill try to explain it this way:

i have these 3 select statements, is there a way to combined them into one statement?

    `SELECT *, CONCAT(C, B, E, D, F) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 1;
    SELECT *, CONCAT(G, C, D, B, E, F) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 2;
    SELECT *, CONCAT(D, E, F, C, B) AS G FROM table WHERE A = 3;`

Comment: What a strange problem. What happens as you add more rows to the table, do you have to update the query? I can't believe this is part of a real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
    CASE A 
        WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT(C, B, E, D, F)
        WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT(C, D, B, E, F)
        WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT(D, E, F, C, B)
    END AS G
FROM table
WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Or you can combine separate queries using `UNION`:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(C, B, E, D, F) AS G
FROM table
WHERE A = 1
UNION
SELECT *, CONCAT(C, D, B, E, F) AS G
FROM table
WHERE A = 2
UNION
SELECT *, CONCAT(D, E, F, C, B) AS G
FROM table
WHERE A = 3
```